# How to detect SKCanvasView full size

Tags: c#, android, maui, skia

Environment: Visual Studio 2022, MAUI Android application, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls nuget 2.88.6.

I am trying to draw `SKImage` in the whole window, stretching it to full width and height. Actually, it is drawn with 1/2 width and height. How can I find the full rectangle from `PaintSurface` message handler?

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Android.Graphics;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;
...

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    SKImage image;
    SKCanvasView canvasView;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ... Other initialization

        canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += CanvasView_PaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    private void CanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        var cv = e.Surface.Canvas;          // SKCanvas

        cv.Clear(new SKColor(0, 0, 255));   // OK, the whole window is blue

        // Left-top point, 1:1
        //cv.DrawImage(image, new SKPoint(0, 0));

        // Trying to draw on the whole area - actually draws about 1/2 width and height
        cv.DrawImage(image, new SKRect(0.0f, 0.0f, (float)canvasView.Width, (float)canvasView.Height));
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml contains only `ContentPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BitmapTest2.MainPage">
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Well SKCanvasView usually matches its container, is your Container spread through the whole screen?

Comment: @FreakyAli: As I understand, the container is the whole `MainPage`, see `Content = canvasView;` line and `MainPage.xaml` from the question.

Comment: Interesting, Maybe try using an AbsoluteLayout or a Grid and Force the Canvas to cover the whole screen? If this does not happen automatically

Comment: @FreakyAli: `cv.Clear` draws the whole window, as expected. The question is edited.

Comment: Ah now I get it what you need to do is use the Width and Height from the Events so basically you would do something like this `var Info = e.Info;` and then get height and width from this `info.Width` and `info.Height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you needed was instead of using Canvas's Height and Width, which are calculated when you add the view to the screen you should check the Info from your PaintSurface's EventsArgs, where the current available space of the Canvas is.

So what you would do is something like below

In your CanvasView_PaintSurface method

```
var info = e.Info;
var height = info.Height;
var width = info.Width;
```